# Why is not possible to edit page content?

Tags: 7, javascript, users

I've been some time without modifying my site in drupal 7, and when I accessed it again, it was not possible to edit the page content anymore. The icon to edit the page content with panels is missing as shown below. 
[image: content page]

It is possible to edit the content of pages that don't have panels.

I am the admin, but the administrator role is not in drupal database.
I am using jquery update module, and set jquery to 1.7. 
I also checked permissions to authenticated users, and it seems to be ok, once this role can create, edit and delete panels and pages.

What can I forgetting to check or update?

Comment: I am the admin, but the administrator role is not in drupal database. 

Are you logged in with USER 1  ?

Comment: Is your browser throwing any javascript errors? If you are logged in as user 1, you should have global permissions to edit anything on the site.

Comment: the browser presents the following errors: Webpage error details User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.3) Timestamp: Thu, 24 Oct 2013 19:54:36 UTC Message: 'jQuery.timeago.settings' is null or not an object Line: 13 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI: .../profiles/commons/modules/contrib/timeago/timeago.js?muzmqt Message: Object doesn't support this property or method Line: 3 Char: 5 Code: 0 URI: .../profiles/commons/modules/contrib/timeago/timeago.js?muzmqt

Comment: Oleg, I am logging as user 1, but I can not find the role administrator in people...